# What's this word?

Tags: meaning

I'm watching a video on youtube and just heard a new word/expression that I can't seem to spell "right enough" to have google correct me and bring me to its definition. I've included the context and put the word/expression in bold below as well as linked to the part of the video that it is taken from.

So, to be clear: what is the word/expression he's using?

> There are certain singers, certain players, you can tell that their
>   overall objective is to make sure you know they're good. And this sort
>   of gets into the overplaying thing and it's not like that was the most
>   **DE MERE** performance I've ever given of a song.

Source: [John Mayer speaking about honesty in songwriting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uiC03q_gMG0#t=17)

Comment: @tchrist - Actually, enough context was given to provide a meaning, as well as a rough idea of what the word sounds like (which beats the heck out of the usual "it starts with a *U* or an *M* or something"). It's every bit as valid a question as any of the other "single word please" questions that have ***ever*** been posted here.

Comment: @bye It’s just as off-topic as any question about a typo. It will not help anybody else, ever. This therefore **does not add value** to the site. Actually, strike that: it’s ***much worse*** than a typo, because it does not embed the questioned material, but relies on some offsite ephemeral link whose continued existence we cannot guarantee. If we open ourselves to this sort of per-hearer question, the flood of billions and billions of questions from non-native speakers who simply do not understand what they are hearing will be unstoppable. This therefore ***subtracts* value from the site**.

Comment: Interesting and valid points on both sides, I must say. I would have agreed with you, hell, even removed the question after an answer was provided, @tchrist, if not for your tone. If you can't see my issue with it, you need to take a chill pill and humble up. **Anyway**, where should questions like this be posted then? What is the appropriate forum for throw-away questions like this?

Comment: I'd also like to add that had I felt that I understood what he (Mayer) was trying to convey then I would've described that too, along with providing the context. That was actually what I first set out to do, but since the context has too many interpretations when you don't know the word it got a bit confusing and I ended up posting the question like I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word is *demure*, which [Collins defines as](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/demure):

> *adjective*
>   1. sedate; decorous; reserved
>     2.  affectedly modest or prim; coy

Comment: Haha, that moment when half of the words in the definition of a word need looking up just to make sure you get all the connotations it carries. Thank you!